# StanfordCoreNLP newlineIsSentenceBreak without removing \n

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, sentence

I have an input text

*My name is ramu\n Im 25 years old.*

I use StanfordCoreNLP to split sentence.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse");
props.put("ssplit.newlineIsSentenceBreak", "always");
props.put("threads", "24");
```

This split my text into two sentences.

1. My name is ramu
2. Im 25 years old.

But I need to keep \n.
My expected result is

1. My name is ramu\n
2. Im 25 years old.

Can any one suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the [`BeforeAnnotation`](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blame/2c05d41638eb977023b7b84ce44525369a4d3a19/src/edu/stanford/nlp/ling/CoreAnnotations.java#L1560) and [`AfterAnnotation`](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blame/2c05d41638eb977023b7b84ce44525369a4d3a19/src/edu/stanford/nlp/ling/CoreAnnotations.java#L469) attached to a `CoreLabel`. This will give you the whitespace before and after the given token, which should include the newline(s). In the Simple API, these are returned by the `before()` and `after()` functions on a sentence.